# How I skip one cell in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make PHP code update column called "downloads" to zero inside MySQL.

After the command executed I want to update **one cell** under the column downloads to "100" for a user called "guest" because the first query reset it to zero.
This is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';
if( $link->query("update users set downloads = 0") ){
    // succesful
} else {
    // fail
}
?>
```

My table structure like this:

```
| NAME | PASSWORD | DOWNLOADS 
| Johny | XieofEnfoEQ | NULL 
| guest | nfOEnfoiJEJj | 100
```

**Is there any way to make the query update all downloads but keep one cell for the user guest without any changing!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust your query to set the `downloads` value to 100 for `guest` and 0 for all others using a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE users
SET downloads = CASE WHEN `NAME` = 'guest' THEN 100 ELSE 0 END
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ivTnbf3edybb16QULcQUjd/0)